# How can I sort an array by another array of objects?

Tags: javascript

How can I sort an array by string?

```
const filter = [
  { index: "First" },
  { index: "Second" },
  { index: "Third" }
]

const data = [
  { title: 'Apple', index: "Second" },
  { title: 'Samsung', index: "First" },
  { title: 'BMW', index: "Third" },
  { title: 'Apple', index: "Second" },
  { title: 'Apple', index: "Second" },
  { title: 'Samsung', index: "First" }
]
```

Expected results:

```
const data = [
  { title: 'Samsung', index: "First" },
  { title: 'Samsung', index: "First" },
  { title: 'Apple', index: "Second" },
  { title: 'Apple', index: "Second" },
  { title: 'BMW', index: "Third" }
]
```

How to iterate over two arrays correctly?
Do I have to iterate over two arrays to do this? Or is there another way to get the desired result?

Given three inputs - "First", "Second", "Third", if there will be more of these indices?

Comment: It’d be easier if `filter` was an array of strings instead of an array of objects. Then something like `data.sort((a, b) => filter.indexOf(a.index) - filter.indexOf(b.index))` would be possible. But `findIndex` could be used here as well.

Answer (score 1):

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over `filter` and save each object's `index` attribute and its index in the array in a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
- Using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), sort `data` by the values of the `index` attributes from the above map

```js
const 
  filter = [ { index: "First" }, { index: "Second" }, { index: "Third" } ],
  data = [ { title: 'Apple', index: "Second" }, { title: 'Samsung', index: "First" }, { title: 'BMW', index: "Third" }, { title: 'Apple', index: "Second" }, { title: 'Apple', index: "Second" }, { title: 'Samsung', index: "First" } ];
  
const indexSortMap = filter.reduce((map, { index }, i) => map.set(index, i), new Map);

data.sort(({ index: a }, { index: b }) => indexSortMap.get(a) - indexSortMap.get(b));

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array#sort` with custom compareFunction and `Array#findIndex` with custom callback function

```js
const filter = [ { index: "First",}, {index: "Second",}, {index: "Third",}];
const data = [ { title: 'Apple', index: "Second" }, { title: 'Samsung', index: "First" }, { title: 'BMW', index: "Third" }, { title: 'Apple', index: "Second" }, { title: 'Apple', index: "Second" }, { title: 'Samsung', index: "First" } ];

data.sort((a ,b) => {
    return filter.findIndex(i => i.index === a.index) - filter.findIndex(i => i.index === b.index);
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution (and simple) is by iterating these two arrays. They will be pushed according to the order of the "filter" array:

```
const sortedArray = []
filter.forEach(fil=> {
  data.forEach(dat=>{
    if(dat.index===fil.index)
      sortedArray.push(dat)
  })
})
console.log(sortedArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to push the objects to three different arrays, each one for an index and then concatenate the arrays.

```js
var arr1 = [],arr2 = [],arr3 = [], data = [ { title: 'Apple', index: "Second" }, { title: 'Samsung', index: "First" }, { title: 'BMW', index: "Third" }, { title: 'Apple', index: "Second" }, { title: 'Apple', index: "Second" }, { title: 'Samsung', index: "First" } ];

for(d of data) d.index == 'First' ? arr1.push(d) : d.index == 'Second' ? arr2.push(d) : arr3.push(d);
data = [].concat.apply([], [arr1, arr2, arr3]);

console.log(data);
```